# How to check date is exceeded 7 days in strtotime() in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Here I am written code for supposing `resetAt` is crossed `24 hrs` means I have set `passwordResetStatus`to `true`, now I want to increase the time like `resetAt` is crossed 7 days means I have to set `passwordResetStatus`to `true` how can I achieve this

```
if(!empty($passwordReset['resetAt'])){ 
    $difference = strtotime(date(DATE_FORMAT)) - strtotime($passwordReset['resetAt']);
    $interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    if($difference >= $interval){
        $data['passwordResetStatus'] = true;
    }else{
        $data['passwordResetStatus'] = false;
    }
    //var_dump($data['passwordResetStatus']);
}
```

> resetAt = 2018-11-08 10:38:55
>
> today = 2018-11-14 10:45:55

based on above condition `passwordResetStatus = true` because `2018-11-08` to `2018-11-14` total 7 days consider time also today time is `10:45:55` reaetAt time `10:38:55` so today time `exceeded` resetAt time .

> resetAt = 2018-11-08 10:38:55
>
> today = 2018-11-14 10:30:55

based on above condition `passwordResetStatus = false` because `2018-11-08` to `2018-11-14` total 7 days consider time also today time is `10:30:55` reaetAt time `10:38:55` so today time `not exceeded` resetAt time.

**We have to consider date & time**

Comment: What is DATE_FORMAT ?

Comment: About that notice: how should we know what `DATE_FORMAT` should mean? Why did you put it there in the first place?

Comment: @ Alive to Die, i have used to your code but not working , please top i have updated my code and response

Comment: @Osama Ibrahim, Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: anyone update my answer separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This simple code

```
$passwordReset['resetAt'] = $restDate = "2018-11-6 11:58:55";
$newDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($restDate.' +6 day'));
$currentDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if( isset( $passwordReset['resetAt'] ) && ($currentDate >= $newDate )){
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = true;
}else{
    $data['passwordResetStatus'] = false;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but not working properly because i am getting  `Array ( [passwordResetStatus] => 1 )` but actual reault should come `Array ( [passwordResetStatus] => 0 )` becase i have resetAt `2018-11-13 11:58:55` +7 days means `2018-11-20 11:58:55` then only `Array ( [passwordResetStatus] => 1 )` correct but today is `2018-11-13 13:24:55`

Comment: so you want resetAt date pluse 7 days with current date right?

Comment: your code also not working properly, please check my edited question

Comment: which issue you currently facing?

Comment: $restDate = "2018-11-08 11:58:55";
$currentDate='2018-11-14 11:55:55'; based on this condition `passwordResetStatus = false`, because 2018-11-08 to 2018-11-14 total 7 days consider time also currentDate time is 11:55:55 restDate time 11:58:55 so currentDate time not exceeded restDate time. this condition not working while using your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer and and also check your both conditions it's working now